# Lock Select Box Size In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, selection, drop-down-menu

This seems like a simple thing, but I cannot figure it out, or find it online.

If I select 5 cells in a column(say A1:A5), and I would like to move this selection shape(column 1:5) over (to B1:B5); Is there shortcut to do this?  Currently I hit the left arrow, and the select box changes size to just B1, and I have to hit shift and select B2:B5.  Ideally I would like to discover a hot key that "locks" the shape of the select box.

It has been suggested by colleagues to write a macro, but this is ineffective in many cases.  For example what if instead of a column I wanted to do the same thing with a row, or with a different sized shape.  It seems likely that excel has this feature built in.

Comment: This question's better for http://superuser.com/, but either way - no, there's no built in feature that lets you shift your selection around. You would need a macro for this - or rather 4 similar macros for each direction.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/238449/how-to-move-selection-in-excel Someone asked the same question, but the answer they got was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how a macro would be ineffective. I would write procedures similar to what's below, then assign them to hotkeys. Let me know if it works for you.

```
Option Explicit

Public rowDim As Long
Public colDim As Long
Public putSel as Boolean

Sub togglePutSel()

putSel = Not putSel

End Sub


Sub GetSelShape()

rowDim = Selection.Rows.Count
colDim = Selection.Columns.Count
putSel = True

End Sub

Sub PutSelShape()

Selection.Resize(rowDim, colDim).Select

End Sub
```

If you want to make it work for whenever you hit the arrow keys, then in your Sheet code, you can use this. You may want to do a quick check that `rowDim` and `colDim` aren't 0. The only issue with this is that you'd be stuck with that behavior unless you create a trigger to stop calling `PutSelShape`. So, I'd suggest one macro (hotkeyed to `GetSelShape`) to toggle it, and another hotkey for `togglePutSel`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If putSel Then
  Call PutSelShape
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify: you can assign `GetSelShape` to Ctrl+m and `togglePutSel` to Ctrl+Shift+M. By default, `putSel` is false. I found it works really well.